# Get weekday number from week name

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an array like below

`result = ['Saturday','Sunday']`

I want to return index for the above days. Like below

`detail= [6,7]`

I tried like below to achieve. But no luck. And I'm new to angular.

`var detail = result.getWeekday()`

Answer (score 0):

string values 'saturday' or 'sunday' on their own are no date values. If you want to link them to days of the week, either declare them as date, or assign a weekday index to them, like this:

```
const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
var result = ["Saturday","Sunday"];
var detail = result.map(x => weekdays.indexOf(x)+1);
```

With Array.map, you can look up the weekday index for each element in your result array.